# How to write a base setup and teardown that runs before every ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, actiondispatch

I have a number of integration tests written using `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` for a Rails 4 app. I'm trying to add a few lines to every `setup` and `teardown` which I want to get called before each test runs, without overriding the `setup` and `teardown` callbacks that are specific to each test.

So basically, I'm looking to do something like the following:

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    super
  end

  teardown do
    Warden.test_reset!
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    super
  end
end
```

I do not want these to overwrite the more specific setups, but rather would like them to run before. So I want this setup to run after the base one written above:

```
class Authorized < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @user = create(:user)
    sign_in(@user)
  end

  test 'some stuff' do
    # Integration test here
  end
end
```

I am currently getting an error with the above:

```
NoMethodError: super called outside of method
```

and so am wondering what the correct way to do this would be. Any advice would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you need super? define method in `Authorized` and call it in setup or `teardown`.

Comment: I basically want `setup` and `teardown` to execute the code in the base class but if there is also a `setup` and `teardown` in the test itself, I want that to be executed too - in reverse order of specificity.

Comment: you can use super only in the method definition, use plain method definition.